# Django - CSV Arabic language encoding

Tags: python, django, csv, encoding, arabic-support

I'm working on Django Python and trying to export data in CSV format as some of the columns are in Arabic and facing issue on encoding

my HttpResponse code

```
HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv charset=utf-8')
```

and CSV file
[image]

how can I solve this Issue ?

Comment: Note: Arabic is not an encoding. So check: are you reading the CSV file as UTF-8? or check which was the original encoding. But from the file I assume it was UTF-8 and you are reading it as maybe Windows "ANSI".

Answer (score 0):

By reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects I found out that there was `;` missing and set `charset=utf-8-sig` resolved my issue

correct line

```
HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig')
```